# How to create an outline - not outline an element - but create a nexted list like an outline

Tags: html, list, nested

I was creating an un-ordered list and came to a point where I wanted to insert another list, that is, nest the lists. I'm using MS Expression Web (very good free tool) and it allows me to indent an `<li>` in the list by using the tab key. It puts another `<ul>` in and then puts in an `<li>` for the nested list.

However, when I switch to code view (which I use most of the time) the nested `<ul>` is flagged as not being allowed inside a `<ul>` by HTML 5.

If I view the page in FF, the nested list looks just as I would expect it to look. The bullets on the main list are black dots, the nested list is indented, and the bullets are circles.

If I change the `<ul>` tags to `<ol>` the nested list is numbered starting at zero.

So, I did a search to find out what tags can be included inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>` and came up with a lot of contradictory information - even here.

So, if HTML 5 does no allow almost any other tags inside a list (I've tried a lot of them to see what the parser says and they were flagged also such as `<p>`, `<div>`. etc.) - is there a tag with which I can create a classic outline with multiple levels?

Such as:

1 - Chapter One
    a - Setting:
        i - The City
        ii - etc.
    b - etc.

When I search on html outline -- I get references to the outline property to create outlines around elements - so there are borders and outlines??

Is there a "legal" way to produce an outline such as show above?

I can't believe there is no  way of creating such an outline (legally)- I mean, outlines are a mainstay in documentation. Heck, table of contents are very often, if not just about always, nested outlines.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I know it's a long time since this question was asked (and answered), but I'm curious where you found "a lot of contradictory information" about what's allowed inside a `ul` or `ol` element. All the official sources (such as [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html) are very clear: permitted content is zero or more `li` elements. That's it. No wiggle room.

Comment: It's been too long to come up with all the sources of information - but, the page you referred to is contradicted on other pages. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp   http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/ul-ol-tags.htm   http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html  search for nest All browsers I've tried (FF IE, Chrome - 2 or 3 releases of each) have no problem with nested lists or with lists containing other elements, not all elements, but many. Seems to be a lot of "wiggle room."

Comment: The W3Schools page doesn't show any indication that it's OK to put anything but a `li` in an `ul`. (Of course you _can_ put whatever you want inside an `li`.)

Comment: You sure are beating that dead horse?. I've used at least 5 validators and 4 browsers and there is not one that has flagged my use of nested lists or other tags inside a list - such as <P - as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any way to create an outline except using nested lists.

I ran the following through a couple of validators and there were no errors or warnings.

So, I guess this answers my question.

```
<ul> <!--beginning of outer list -->
    <li>
        First line of outline, outer list
    </li>
    <li>
        Second line of outline, outer list
        <ul> <!--beginning of first nested list-->
            <li>
                First line of first nested list
            </li>
            <li>
                Second line of 1st nested list
                <ul> <!-- beginning 2nd nested list -->
                    <li>
                        First line of 2nd nested list
                    </li>
                </ul>  <!-- end of 2nd nested list -->
            </li>  <!-- end of list item in which 2nd nested list exists
        </ul>  <!-- end of 1st nested list-->
    </li> <!-- end of of list item which contains 1st nested list -->
    <li>
        Third line of Outline, non nested
    </li>
<ul> <!-- end outer list -->
```

Produces the following:

- First line of outline, outer list
- Second line of outline, outer list

  - First line of first nested list
  - Second line of 1st nested list

    - First line of 2nd nested list
- Third line of Outline, non nested

Comment: Set the CSS [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) to use numbers or Roman numerals on your list items. And remember that you should be using `<ol>`, not `<ul>`, for numbered lists.

Comment: I assume your comment refers to the fact that I "titled" the lines "First line.." "Second line.." etc. That was simply to explain the structure of the list. I am aware of the correct use of both ordered and Un-ordered lists. I simply choose to use ul for this question. You can also set CSS rules so that alphabetic characters are used on an ol, not just numbers or roman numerals.

Comment: The point was to point out the CSS property that you seemed to be unaware of. That is all.